# Variable 'Number' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: Подскажите как решить данную проблему]

Подскажите пожалуйста,как в InfoWindow вывести текст без `final String`, ибо иначе все маркеры будут с одним текстом.
Мне требуется вывести в InfoWindow порядка 3-4 разных строк.
Ниже фрагмент кода с скрина.

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            if(dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue() != null &&
                    dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue() != null) {
                double latt = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                double longg = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(latt, longg);
                String sname = (String) dataSnapshot.child("sname").getValue();
                String text = (String) dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue();
                String Number = (String) dataSnapshot.child("number").getValue();
                String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
                if (image.equals("akym")) {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(newLocation)
                            .title(sname)
                            .snippet("Номер:"+Number+"\n"+"Описание:"+text)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.akym))
                    );
                    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                            View myContentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                    R.layout.custommarker, null);
                            TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.title));
                            tvTitle.setText(Number);
                            TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.snippet));
                            tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                            return myContentView;
                        }
                    });
```

*P.S Я знаю что код ужасен,но я учусь)*

Comment: Вам нужно устанавливать `InfoWindowAdapter` один раз, а данные для отображения передавать через `setTag`/`getTag` у `Marker` ([пример](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#associate_data_with_a_marker)).

Comment: @zRrr , к сожалению не очень понял как это использовать...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы получить доступ к переменной в inner классе метода, есть несколько вариантов:

1. Вы можете либо сделать переменную глобальной (задать в теле класса) и в методе лишь менять/задавать значение.
2. Вы можете внутри метода сделать финальную переменную-массив с единственным элементом: `final String[] number = new String[1]` и работать с ним: `number[0] = "Текст"`; `tvTitle.setText(number[0])` и т.д.

Comment: `.snippet("Имя:"+sname+"\n"+"Номер:"+Number+"\n"+"Описание:"+text)

                            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                                View myContentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                        R.layout.custommarker, null);
                                TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentView
                                        .findViewById(R.id.snippet));
                                tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                                return myContentView;` вот так вроде получилос

Comment: Сделал то,что хотел в принципе)Но за ответ спасибо)